# ReferenceError when adding a Leaflet Icon to a custom Type in NextJs

Tags: typescript, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to add different kinds of Icons to a React Leaflet map, but getting an error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

This only happens when I include a Leaflet Icon in my custom type. Without this Icon, the map rendering works perfectly, but I am looking for a way where different Icons can be generated. My Map.tsx file looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  Popup,
  Marker as Marker2,
  useMapEvents,
} from "react-leaflet";
import {
  type LatLngExpression,
} from "leaflet";
import { Icon } from "leaflet";
import { ForestTypes } from "../../../types/leaflet";


export default function Map({ forestType }: { forestType: ForestTypes }) {
  const initialArray: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    image: string;
    iconName: Icon;
  }[] = [];
  const [forestArray2, setForestArray2] = useState(initialArray);


  const LocationFinderDummy = () => {
    const map = useMapEvents({
      click(e) {
        setForestArray2((prevValue) => [
          ...prevValue,
          {
            lat: e.latlng.lat,
            lng: e.latlng.lng,
            image: forestType.image,
            iconName: forestType.iconName,
          },
        ]);
      },
    });

    return null;
  };

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={{ lat: 0.67, lng: 114.0 }}
      zoom={7}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
    >
      <LocationFinderDummy />

      {forestArray2.map((item, index) => (
        <Marker2  
          icon={item.iconName}
          key={index}
          position={[item.lat, item.lng]}
          title={`${item.lat}`}
        />
      ))}

      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"
      />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

And I am calling it from where the user is able to select which icon they want to add to the map:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { forestTypes } from "../../data/ForestTypes";
import classNames from "classnames";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { type ForestTypes } from "../../types/leaflet";
import Image from "next/image";
import { green } from "../../data/ForestTypes";

const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("../components/Map/Map"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [forestType, setForestType] = useState<ForestTypes>({
    id: 1,
    name: "Forest1",
    image: "images/three.svg",
    iconName: green,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <section id="hero">
          <div className="sm:py-18 bg-white py-12 px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl text-center">
              <div>
                {forestTypes.map((forest) => (
                  <button
                    className={classNames(
                      forest !== forestType ? "" : "bg-blue-200",
                      " px-6 py-5 text-center text-sm font-medium"
                    )}
                    key={forest.id}
                    onClick={() => setForestType(forest)}
                  >
                    <Image
                      src={forest.image}
                      height="100"
                      width="100"
                      alt="forest"
                    />
                    <div className="flex flex-row justify-center py-2">
                      {forest.name}
                    </div>
                  </button>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <div className="z-0 mx-auto w-3/4">
          <MapWithNoSSR
            key={new Date().getTime()}
            forestType={forestType}
          />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Where my ForestTypes are defined as:

```
import { Icon } from "leaflet";
import { type ForestTypes } from "../types/leaflet";

export const green = new Icon({
  iconUrl: "/images/tree.svg",
  iconSize: [36, 36],
});

export const pink = new Icon({
  iconUrl: "/images/tree2.svg",
  iconSize: [36, 36],
});

export const forestTypes: ForestTypes[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Forest1",
    image: "/images/tree.svg",
    iconName: green,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Forest2",
    image: "/images/tree2.svg",
    iconName: pink,
  },
];
```

And in leaflet.d.ts I have:

```
import type { Icon } from "leaflet";

export interface ForestTypes {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  iconName: Icon;
}
```

I am already importing the Leaflet map dynamically and disabling SSR, but when trying to use the Icon I am getting the same error message again.

Has anyone else experienced this, or have any ideas of how I could render my map with the different kinds of Icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your svgs accessible on the urls you provide? When I look into the leaflet marker typings I noticed that `Icon` also have a `imagePath` that you could try to use instead.

However I have great success with using `DivIcon` for custom markers.
DivIcons can handled static html, which means that you can use any html you want and with some code you can use ReactElements.

```js
import { divIcon } from "leaflet";
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";

export const createLeafletIcon = (
  icon: ReactElement,
  size: number,
  className?: string,
  width: number = size,
  height: number = size,
  center: boolean = false
) => {
  const widthAnchor = width / 2;
  const heightAnchor = center ? height / 2 : height;
  return divIcon({
    html: renderToString(icon),
    iconSize: [width, height],
    iconAnchor: [widthAnchor, heightAnchor],
    popupAnchor: [0, -heightAnchor],
    className: className ? className : "",
  });
};
```

In your case just prepare the icons as react components that you can reuse in other instances in your application as well.

This is my custom marker component for some context

```js
import { LatLngLiteral } from "leaflet";
import React, { Children, ReactElement, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Marker, Popup, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import { MapPin } from "tabler-icons-react";
import { createLeafletIcon } from "./utils";

export interface LeafletMarkerProps {
  position: LatLngLiteral;
  flyToPosition?: boolean;
  size?: number;
  color?: string;
  icon?: ReactElement;
  defaultOpen?: boolean;
  onOpen?: () => void;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  markerType?: string;
  zIndexOffset?: number;
  centerMarker?: boolean;
}

const LeafletMarker: React.FC<LeafletMarkerProps> = ({
  position,
  flyToPosition = false,
  children,
  size = 30,
  color,
  defaultOpen = false,
  onOpen,
  icon = <MapPin size={size} color={color} />,
  markerType,
  zIndexOffset,
  centerMarker = false,
}) => {
  const map = useMap();

  const markerRef = useRef(null);
  position && flyToPosition && map.flyTo(position);

  const markerIcon = createLeafletIcon(
    icon,
    size,
    markerType,
    size,
    size,
    centerMarker
  ); // Important to not get default styling
  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultOpen) {
      try {
        if (markerRef.current !== null && !markerRef.current.isPopupOpen()) {
          markerRef.current.openPopup();
        }
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  }, [defaultOpen, position.lat, position.lng]);

  return (
    <Marker
      eventHandlers={{
        popupopen: () => onOpen && onOpen(),
      }}
      ref={markerRef}
      icon={markerIcon}
      position={position}
      zIndexOffset={zIndexOffset}
    >
      {/* autoPan important to not have jittering */}
      {children && <Popup autoPan={false}>{children}</Popup>}
    </Marker>
  );
};

export default LeafletMarker;
```

Comment: Thanks, Disco, you are correct that it was by referring to the images the way I did that caused the error! I implemented a temporary fix by defining my Icons inside the map component but I will revisit your implementation once I need to make further updates!